# Eclipse - How to import custom library JSocket

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add the JSocket library in Eclipse Luna.

How?

This is the link for JSocket.

https://github.com/czifro-tech/JSocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigth click on your project > Properties > 
Then select "Java Build Path" menu,
Navigate until Libraries tab and click on "Add JARs..." button,
Select the JSocket Jar on your folder and be happy.